# How to incorporate checkstyle on a website?

Tags: web-applications, real-time, checkstyle, vs-web-application-project

I am creating an real-time code compiler web app and I am wanting to incorporate checkstyle into the text editor. Does anyone know how to do this or where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download code to a server and create temporary file out of it, because Checkstyle operates on files.

Then it's a matter of invoking analysis. You can look into code of e.g. Maven Checkstyle Plugin, CheckStyle-IDEA or other similar tools to learn how to run Checkstyle on a given file and get the results back.